# How deep should my math background be before tackling SICP?

Tags: math, scheme

HI,
I've been trying to work my way thru the SICP book, I found myself cribbing some of the online answers but getting the overall ideas of recursive vs. iterative procedures, etc. But I'm getting to the orders of growth section, and the math is really over my head.

To give an idea of my math skills, this morning I spent an hour learning how to add and subtract fractions with exponents....

Anyway, my math chops *have* to come way up, and I will work on that. But is there a short list of concepts to be familiar with before tackling SICP? I WILL tackle that damn book if it kills me...I think it's awesome, but I want to approach it in the best way possible.

Right now I'm thinking my time might be best used tackling some fundamental algorithms while I'm getting my math chops together.

Any recommendations? 
Thanks!
bp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like SICP would be way too heavy for you.  Try out [HtDP](http://htdp.org/) instead for a book that will teach you programming in a similar style but much easier on the math.

Comment: Will this prepare the OP to read SICP? I haven't read all of HtDP so I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: It will help with the (functional) programming aspects, but obviously not with the math.

Answer (score 6):

Ideally, you should have some calculus skills to go through SICP.  Being able to integrate and differentiate functions would be the highest-level math that I've come across so far.  (I'm currently working my way through it myself)

Comment: I disagree -- there are a few instances where calculus would be helpful, but otherwise precalculus mathematics should be enough.

Comment: @JasonS "enough" in the sense that you can still use the book and learn from it, but many of the code examples and exercises in the 1st chapter deal with numerical integration and differentiation. The book does a decent job of explaining some of it, but I imagine it would be a little bit of a shock for someone who doesn't know calculus to come across these terms in addition to the Scheme and programming knowledge that they are learning.

Answer (score 5):

So, at MIT, people would take the SICP class in first year after tackling calculus for a semester. The first time I went through the book, the math was way over my head. As I trudged through my university calculus class, a lot of the first chapter made more sense. **You're probably going to be more comfortable going through the book with at least a first year calculus course under your belt.**

That being said, I started the book before returning to university for a CS degree. At first, I wasn't able to grok all the math examples, but I still understood what was being conveyed. Revisiting the chapters after learning calculus merely enriched the experience. It wasn't a requirement.

I'm only about half way through the book, but from what I see, **it's only the first few chapters of the book the require any kind of math skill.** Hard work and skipping over select questions will get you over those humps.

I hope you do decide to go through the book. It's quite an enlightening experience.

Answer (score 1):

Some discrete math would be also be very useful for SICP.  I recommend Rosen's [Discrete Math](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0072424346).  I got a copy of the 5th edition and Solutions Manual for $12 at Half Price Books.